# How to render extended ASCII characters in terminal using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, terminal, extended-ascii

According to [this site](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/graphic-character-high-density-dotted-ascii-code-178.html), ASCII extended character codes 176, 177 and 178 correspond to three characters consisting in different shades of rectangles:

[image: characters]

Here in more detail, character 178:

[image: character]

Now, according to https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes, I should be able to escape any ASCII character with a code below 256 with, for example, its hex escape sequence. So, 176 would be `\xB0` in hex. But instead of getting the expected character as described above, I get "degree symbol" `'°'`. Degree symbol is ASCII 248, not 176, so.... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The key point is "*IBM developed an extension of 8-bit ASCII code, called "code page 437"*". It's one of many extensions. http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript uses **[Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/en/)**, rather than extended ASCII. You can find the  Unicode equivalent of the ASCII symbols by using **[String.prototype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)**, and then output them with **[String.prototype.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)**:

```js
console.log("░".charCodeAt(0)); // 9617
console.log("▒".charCodeAt(0)); // 9618
console.log("▓".charCodeAt(0)); // 9619

console.log(String.fromCharCode(9617)); // ░
console.log(String.fromCharCode(9618)); // ▒
console.log(String.fromCharCode(9619)); // ▓
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks! It confused me that in https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal it says "Any character with a character code lower than 256 (i.e. any character in the extended ASCII range) can be escaped using its hex-encoded character code". They key here is "character code" which refers to Unicode Character Codes, not ASCII... I missed that.

Comment: Be aware that String.fromCharCode(x) will not work for extended ascii as Unicode is compatible up the the 127 first characters (on 7 bits). For exemple String.fromCharCode(232) will give 'è' as unicode but it is 'Φ' in extended ascii

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript deals in Unicode, not Extended ASCII.

[U+00B0 is the degree symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm)

[Block elements hold positions 2580 to 259F](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2580-259F)

```js
console.log("\u2592");
```